# How to remove trailing slash before URL parameters in Nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I have an simple Nginx site that runs a single PHP file regardless of the URL (except for CSS/JS files, which are served normally)

However, no matter what I do, and testing with multiple browsers, any time I include GET/URL parameters, it adds a trailing slash right before the `?`. For example:

- `example.com?test=1` redirects to => `example.com/?test=1`
- `example.com/path?test=1` redirects to => `example.com/path/?test=1`

This is the config I am currently using

```
    index index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include                         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index                   index.php;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are being caught by one of the nginx rules discussed
[here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which says...

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash
> character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass,
> fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, memcached_pass, or grpc_pass,
> then the special processing is performed. In response to a request
> with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a
> permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested
> URI with the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of
> the URI and location could be defined like this:

and there is more discussion. I think your example URI is actually processed by the first location spec (which obvious ends with a slash) so the request URI has a slash added.

a location specification like `location ~ .*$ { commands; }` might work better